# How to mix Silverlight DataGrid columns with and without binding?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

In Silverlight 4 I have a DataGrid which is bound to a RIA DomainDataSource, all done in XAML. The `AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to `false` and each column is manually defined and bound. Basically this works fine.

Where I now run into problems is having an additional `DataGridTextColumn` which has no Binding. I want to manually populate the cells in this column in the code behind. When having this column without the Binding, at runtime the following exception pops up:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: binding
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingOperations.SetBinding(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp, BindingBase binding)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn.GenerateElement(DataGridCell cell, Object dataItem)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.PopulateCellContent(Boolean isCellEdited, DataGridColumn dataGridColumn, DataGridRow dataGridRow, DataGridCell dataGridCell)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.AddNewCellPrivate(DataGridRow row, DataGridColumn column)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.CompleteCellsCollection(DataGridRow dataGridRow)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.GenerateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 slot, Object dataContext)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.AddSlots(Int32 totalSlots)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.RefreshRows(Boolean recycleRows, Boolean clearRows)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.RefreshRowsAndColumns(Boolean clearRows)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.InitializeElements(Boolean recycleRows)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DataGridDataConnection.NotifyingDataSource_CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSourceView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSourceView.OnCollectionViewCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.EntityCollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollectionView.RefreshView()
   at System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollectionView.SourceCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.Controls.EntityCollectionView.HandleSourceCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollection.RaiseCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Entity entity, Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Controls.PagedEntityCollection.CompleteLoad()
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSource.ProcessLoadedEntities(LoadContext loadContext, IEnumerable`1 entities)
   at System.Windows.Controls.DomainDataSource.DomainContext_Loaded(LoadedDataEventArgs e, LoadContext loadContext)
```

How can I avoid this exception and have my DataGrid with most columns bound and one column unbound?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

My XAML looks as follows:

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Data, ElementName=MyDomainDataSource, Mode=OneWay}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding CreationDate}" Header="Creation Date" />
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Unbound Col" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

**Edit #2:**

One idea I found on the web was to bind the last column to some unique value (I have an ID in my data model) and use a custom `IValueConverter` which converts the ID to a dependent value. This would have been exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately I get the dependent value from a WCF service call, which is always asynchronous. As you cannot use async method calls in an `IValueConverter` this solution is not an option for me.

Comment: Can you show your associate Xaml?

Comment: I added the XAML code for my DataGrid in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a DataGridTemplateColumn instead?   It does not matter if you set the binding or not for this type of column.

For example, if you just want to set the unbound value once at the time of loading you could do something like this:

```
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox x:Name="MyText" Loaded="MyText_Loaded"></TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

...and then set the value in the code behind like this:

```
    private void MyText_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if (textBox != null) textBox.Text = "My one off text"; 
    }
```

I'm not sure what your exact requirements are.

Comment: I tried that and indeed it works without binding. However, I didn't find a way to insert some value for the cells in that column programatically. Do I have to modify the DataSource in order to get access to the values?

Comment: Can you show us the XAML for your DataGridTemplateColumn column?

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it could be a solution. However, I get the value for each cell in the unbound column from a WCF web service (see my above edit #2). Do you know a solution for that problem?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to redesign your underlying data objects that you are binding the grid to.  You could create a custom POCO class that contains all of the values required and then bind a collection of them to the grids ItemsSource i.e All columns should be bindable.  In summary, sort out your data source first rather than trying to re-engineer the grid.

Comment: Probably you are right, I should redesign the data objects. However, for now I went for your above solution with the DataGridTemplateColumn and the Loaded event for each TextBlock in which I call the web service to get the missing value. In my case that's ok because there are only very few rows (maximum 10). Thanks again.